# How to use an android accessibility service to detect which view the user touched?

Tags: java, android, accessibility, accessibilityservice

There's something that android TalkBack does that I want to do too. Specifically it's to identify the view that the user touched. I made this so far:

```
@Override
public void onAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent event) {
    if (event.getEventType() == AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_VIEW_CLICKED) {

        //This only shows the package of the activity that the view is in, I want to identify the view itself
        Toast.makeText(this, "" + event.getSource().getPackageName(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the view's id, but I think you can only access the `AccessibilityNodeInfo` associated with the view - I don't think you have access to the view itself. You can [check the docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/accessibility/AccessibilityEvent) for more information on this.

```
    // kotlin code
    event.source.viewIdResourceName
    // or
    findFocusedViewInfo().viewIdResourceName
```

According to the [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/accessibility/AccessibilityNodeInfo#getViewIdResourceName()):

> Gets the fully qualified resource name of the source view's id.
> Note: The primary usage of this API is for UI test automation and in order to report the source view id of an AccessibilityNodeInfo the client has to set the AccessibilityServiceInfo#FLAG_REPORT_VIEW_IDS flag when configuring the AccessibilityService.

Comment: Can an accessibility service report the view ID of every node or will it return null for some nodes?

Comment: If a node does not have an id, like most labels, or a button that has the onClick method assigned in XML and therefore has no id, it will probably be null. That is what I have experienced with `adb shell uiautomator dump`

Answer (score 0):

the question is not clear, but maybe this will help you:-

```
@Override 
public void onAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent event) {
    AccessibilityNodeInfo source = event.getSource(); 

    if (source == null) {
        return; 
    } 
    List<AccessibilityNodeInfo> findAccessibilityNodeInfosByViewId = source.findAccessibilityNodeInfosByViewId("YOUR PACKAGE NAME:id/RESOURCE ID FROM WHERE YOU WANT DATA"); 

    if (findAccessibilityNodeInfosByViewId.size() > 0) {
        AccessibilityNodeInfo parent = (AccessibilityNodeInfo) findAccessibilityNodeInfosByViewId.get(0);
        // You can also traverse the list if required data is deep in view hierarchy. 
        String requiredText = parent.getText().toString();
        Log.i("Required Text", requiredText);
    }
}
```

also read this [tutorial](https://web.archive.org/web/20161228170758/http://axovel.com/blog/2016/05/06/taking-accessibility-service-to-next-level-android/)

Comment: This just gets the accessibility text of the node. I need an id that is always available for each node and that is unique. Meaning something that identifies a node among other nodes.